# jQuery access to serialized data

Tags: jquery, variables, serialization

I need to pass some variables from a cookie to jQuery, but I got this result:

```
a:2:{s:4:"wait";s:3:"600";s:2:"ip";i:168427521;}
```

Which is serialized, how I can access to these variables from jQuery?

Edit: I've updated my code: now I got this:

```
console.log(cookie);
```

and prints:

```
{"wait":"600","ip":168427521}
```

how I can access those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(cookie);
console.log(obj.wait,obj.ip);`
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to deserialize php serialized vars using javascript, there's nothing like that in jquery (not a builtin at least)

You've got several options here:

1- deserialize with php and pass that to js as json

2- change serialization and use json (json serialization is builtin in jQuery) also for the cookie

3- use something like this to deserialize php objects to javascript -> http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize:571 so that you can do something like in js

```
unserialize('a:2:{s:4:"wait";s:3:"600";s:2:"ip";i:168427521;}');
```